# Proper way to require file that requires db connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, templates

I don't use php very often and was wondering if someone could answer this question for me.

I have a folder structure like so:

```
-pages/rightCol.php
-pages/privacyPolicy.php
index.php
```

In my index file I have a connection to the database like this:

```
ob_start();
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/inc/db.inc.php");
```

That works fine.

I wanted to separate out some repeated code between pages so I created the rightCol.php file.  It needs the connection to the database.  So right now I create a query result at the top of the index file and use the statement:

This works.

I also wanted to include it in the privacyPolicy.php page.  This does not work because I do not want to put the query code at the top of every page that requires the rightCol.php file.

I would like to put the db stuff inside the rightCol.php.  When I try this, then my privacyPolicy.php file works but then my index breaks.  Probably because I require the db file twice, once at the top of the index and once in the rightCol.php file.

How can I set this up properly where I do not need to repeat code.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I changed my call to use require_once.

The privacyPolicy.php page works fine but when I view my index.php it has errors.

Error: No DB selected.

Comment: Use [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Include the `db/inc.php` only at the start of your index.php and open the connection. That way, it will stay open throughout the whole script. Then just close it at the very end of your site;
2. If you are having problem knowing where to include and not ( and still for some unknown reason want to include it more then once ), then get used to `require_once` method. This way the file will be included only once and the 2nd attempt will be ignored.

Comment: I ended up just putting the php code in a header file that is on every page.  It works now.  The only bad thing is that some pages do not need the query that is needed on the index file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the quick way to solve the problem is to use `require_once`. But i highly recommend that you use a [micro-framework](http://microphp.org/) like [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/).